# Problem detecting orientation of phone

Tags: android, configuration, orientation

In my onCreate method, I'd like to detect the orientation and set an appropriate background image.

I can get the orientation like so:

```
    Display dis = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = dis.getOrientation();
```

I've tested this on both the Galaxy S and the Moment.

When I am in portrait mode, this returns a value of 0.  When I am in landscape mode, this returns a value of 1.

However, the define Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE has a value of 2 and the define Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT has a value of 1.

So, when I turn the phone to landscape mode, it gives me Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT.  And when I turn the phone to portrait mode, it gives me Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED.

What is going on???

I'm using API level 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check orientation on Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is just put the landscape drawable into a `/drawable-land/` folder, and Android will pull it automatically depending on the orientation. Rather than relying on that, though, you would be better off to make a landscape version of the layout under `/layout-land/` that has the alternate version as its background.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answers in [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

Comment: for a short fix im using this (using the height and width to determine orientation)