# Get device rotation when auto-rotate is off

Tags: android, android-orientation

I'm writing a camera app which disables auto-rotation during the camera preview by setting `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"`.  However, I'd still like to know the rotation of the phone when the picture is taken.  `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` is not specific enough, only returning portrait, landscape or square.  `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()` is always 0 since the screen is forced to be in its default orientation - how can I get what that value *would* be if auto-rotation were on?

Comment: If you're curious about the "would be" you're going to have to use the gyroscope and detect the actual rotation of the device in real time.

Comment: u can get help here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697631/android-screen-orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) class for receiving notifications from the SensorManager when the orientation of the device has changed.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit in depth but worked well for tracking the orientation changes. I used it to get the photo orientation when the camera intent was opened and a photo was taken. I then knew what orientation the photo was. It obviously doesn't work for the photo library but you can use exif information for that. I discovered, much to my horror, that the Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4 were not returning exif orientation data from the camera.

```
//keep a history
private int [] _orientationHistory = new int[5];
private int _orientationIndex;
private int _highestIndex = -1;
private int _currentOrientation;

//essentially compute the mode of the data. This could be improved
protected int getOrientation()
{
    if (_highestIndex < 0) return 0;

    Arrays.sort(_orientationHistory);
    return _orientationHistory[_highestIndex / 2];
}

OrientationEventListener _imageViewOrientationListener = new            
              OrientationEventListener(getContext(), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {
public void onOrientationChanged(int angle) {
        //angle comes in 360 degrees, convert that to a 0-3 rotation
        //Get the angle in 90 degree increments, 0,90,180,270 
        //with 45 degrees tolerance in each direction (straight up is 0) 
        //this is the same as the data coming from getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()

        angle = angle + 45;
        if (angle > 360) angle = angle - 360;
        int orientation = angle / 90;

        //I use a history in order to smooth out noise 
        //and don't start sending events about the change until this history is filled
        if (_orientationIndex > _highestIndex) {
            _highestIndex = _orientationIndex;
        }
        _orientationHistory[_orientationIndex] = orientation;
        _orientationIndex ++;

        if (_orientationIndex == _orientationHistory.length) {
            _orientationIndex = 0;
        }

        int lastOrientation = _currentOrientation;
        //compute the orientation using above method
        _currentOrientation = getOrientation();

        if (_highestIndex == _orientationHistory.length - 1 && lastOrientation != _currentOrientation) {
            //enough data to say things changed
            orientationChanged(lastOrientation, _currentOrientation);
        }
    }
};
```

Then to enable this listener just add this line of code:

```
if (_imageViewOrientationListener != null) {
     _imageViewOrientationListener.enable();
}
```

Lastly, add the method orientationChanged() and receive updates when the orientation changed.
If you need to as I did, start recording this info when you've opened the camera activity and if the orientation flipped to something different, say landscape from portrait, you can assume the pic taken during that time period is the rotation change you recorded.

```
protected void orientationChanged(int lastOrientation, int currentOrientation) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Orientation changed to " + currentOrientation + " from " + lastOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In activity you can use

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {    //this method return you latest configuration
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
//  newConfig.orientation  //Using this you will able to get orientation of device
}
```

This method calls after you changed device configuration.

Comment: Note that the orientation reported via the configuration changes mechanism reports only landscape or portrait, not the full orientation set including portrait-upside down and landscape-left vs. landscape right.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to configuration changed

```
<activity
...
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
...
```

In onConfigurationChanged() you can force the orientation you want (e.g portrait) but getting information about orientation changes.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    //get new configuration orientation from newConfig.orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

And don't use android:screenOrientation="portrait" so when user change the orientation onConfigurationChanged will be called.