# minVersion 8 (2.2) - What can replace these functions?

Tags: android

```
// I use this method to determine the change screen orientation    
Activity.isChangingConfiguration()
```

and

```
ColorDrawable.getColor() // I use this method to get activity background color
```

These methods were added in api version 11.
Now I have to use minimum version of api - 8.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This work for color

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_light);
```

For orientation: [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697631/android-screen-orientation). Try using google, or this website search engine :) Good luck

Comment: What is R.color.gray_light ? I not found it in android.R.color .

Comment: R.color.gray_light is path to my costume color.xml file in resource directory. You can use Color. which is default implemented in android. Like "Color.BLACK"

Comment: in Your case, it will be empty getColor();