# Obtaining screen orientation in GLES renderer (android)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, screen-orientation

I'm looking for a more elegant solution for obtaining the screen orientation in the GLES renderer in my code.  I would like the clearcolor (among other things) in my OpenGLES view to change when the screen orientation changes.  Right now I have a really kluge solution in the `onSurfaceChanged` method where I fib a little:

```
int orientation;

if (height > width) {
    orientation = 0;
} else {
    orientation = 1;
}
```

This is not really what I want, since height and width could potentially be equal or even inverted if the GLES code gets used in a smaller sub-view later on.  Can someone suggest a better way to allow the renderer to check the screen orientation when `onSurfaceChanged` is called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697631/android-screen-orientation

Comment: Basically, your question has nothing to do with OpenGL ES and is related only to getting orientation of Android device. Please be patient and do a better search over SO next time, @Submersed have pointed you to necessary question.

Comment: I'm just now starting to realize my noobness.  I did see that question on  my initial search, but trying the code didn't work.  I guess my problem is figuring out how to access resources like the window manager when I'm not inside the Activity class.  Apparently this is a much more fundamental issue....