# How do I prevent my app from rotating /prevent the orientation switch once I lock the screen?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation, android-screen

I am trying to prevent myy app orientation to landscape to portrait or vice versa when I lock the screen by clicking screen rotation to off.I saw that once I deselect screen rotation, the entire screen locks up including the screen of the apps I have on my device except for my app where orientation change still triggers landscape portrait recognition even when locked.How do I go around it? DoI need to set something in android manifest to make it work in accordance with the screen rotation ?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you why you need/want to prevent the orientation switch after the screen lock?

Comment: I want it to adhere to the normal behavior like all the other apps, when you deselect screen rotation/lock the device screen, all the other apps remain in the particular orientation

Comment: This post should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697631/android-screen-orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can set either add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` parameter to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**edit:**
You can also "lock" screen orientation programmatically using [setRequestedOrientation (int requestedOrientation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29)

Comment: I don't want to restrict the behavior of my app. It works fine as is.I just want it to lock the orientation when I lock my whole device by unclicking screen rotation ,I want my app to be just like the other app and remain in the orientation it is whether landscape or portrait once the screen rotation button is unselected on the device

Comment: where do I do it programmatically? in my main activity?

Comment: I the Activity that you want to lock. See this topic for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: that didn't help. Can you provide a sample code for say main activity with oncreate methods, very generic way to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock orientation when user locks it in the system you need to add `android:screenOrientation="user"` in your `activity` tag

Comment: didn't have any luck with this