# android portrait or landscape

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

how to know programatically whether screen is in portrait or landscape mode.please help me

Answer (score 22):

```
if(context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
{
    // code to do for Portrait Mode
} else {
    // code to do for Landscape Mode         
}
```

Answer (score 3):

getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

or for listening to orientation events : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

or use `OrientationEventListener`

Answer (score 3):

Use getResources().getConfiguration().orientation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the current width and height. If the height is longer than the width the screen is in portrait mode, otherwise it is landscape.