# how do I know what the orientation is in android?

Tags: android, orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

I am writing an app that requires my program to know the difference between whether it is in landscape mode, or in portrait. how would I go about finding this out. currently I am using the getRequestedOrientation(), but that is always returning the number 2, which basically just means that it will change depending on which way the phone is turned (as apposed to being 0 which is landscape, or 1 which is portrait.) is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in [`onConfigurationChanged(Configurtion)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges), the configuration object holds the information about the orientation. According to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html), it can either be PORTRAIT, SQUARE or LANDSCAPE only.

Answer (score 6):

You can check this in methods other than `onConfigurationChanged` by using the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone/2799001#2799001):

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

which will be equal to [one of the following](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation):

- Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
- Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
- Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE