# Different activities for landscape and portrait

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, orientation

I have no idea of this is actually possible, but i want the device to have different activities for landscape and portrait.
I have a listview, and of all the items in my listview i have the coordinates. So i thought, it would be nice if you put your device in landscape, and show a mapview with icons placed on the locations of the items.

I know you can create different layouts for different orientations, but only creating an mapview and using that as landscape layout wont do the trick i guess. Is there something possible in an equivalent way for activities? I couldn't find it, so probably not.

Else i think this might work:
I thought myself of a switch in the activity: on portrait --> do this and load this layout, on landscape --> do that and use the other layout. But this would only work once if put in the oncreate. But than the [orientationlistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) would do the trick. Anyone knows of this is possible?

Comment: Just my two cents on the matter; I don't think this would be a very good experience. If the user accidentally rotates the screen, they're suddenly looking at something very different. Seems confusing.

Comment: try adding different layouts for landscape and portrait view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in activity lifecycle

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                
            // Check the Orientation of Device
            // Start Other Activity
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

you can use this method to change the activity if the device orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO we can't use 2 different activities here, but there is a way,

please check out how to detect orientation dynamically here,
[check-orientation-on-android-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

once you are through this, you can include code for landscape mode here in the same activity.