# Android Capture Orientation Change

Tags: android, orientation

I have two background images. I want Image A to display when the screen is horizontal and Image B to display when the screen is vertical. Any easy way of achieving this?

Comment: Check orientation on Android phone http://stackoverflow.com/q/2795833/1012284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
Result Values for Oreintations will be:-  
Portrait  == 1  
Landscape == 2
```

```
int i = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (i == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
   yourimg.setBackground(yourAimage);
} else {
   yourImg.setBackground(yourBimage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create two xml layouts here one for landscape and other for portrait. In portrait xml you can add different images for background. By this we can use two different layouts for two orientations for a single activity. see the below picture, hope it should help.

[image]

Comment: I want to keep my layout's the same, and just change the background.

Comment: create the same layout in both layout and layout-land folder with the different Background images.. Now u will get ur expected result..

Comment: @James Fazio you have to create two xml files with same name, one under layout landscape and other under layout-portrait.

Answer (score 1):

take two images A & B. save image A in drawable-land and image B in drawable-port

note that the images are saved with same names..

you can check this in graphic layout also..

Comment: Do I have to capture an orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

Create each XML for horizontal & Vertical

Create one more folder name "layout-land"
n just coy & paste the main.xml(your layout file) and just change the background respectavely.

you'll done...