# Auto fit Screen in android When changing Orientation

Tags: android

Is there any way to auto fit the screen when changing the orientation?

Because when I view my App in Portrait mode all the images seems fined but when I change it into Landscape the images becomes pix-elated or has been stretched to much. So I'm wondering if there is auto fit screen.

thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Try to use layout_weight="1"

Comment: I think your image are set "FIT_XY". Try to set fit as FIT_CENTER. As second possibility you can create a second layout for landscape orientation, so you can re-design layout as you want.

Comment: how can I check if the Orientation has been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify different layouts with same name in layout-land folder and use suitable drawables. 
For more help see this tutorial

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-portrait-amp-landscape-differeent-layouts

Comment: how can I check if the Orientation has been changed?

Comment: if you do this way, then OS will automatically render the layout according to orientation

Comment: Btw this is how u can get Orientation at run time:

 Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = display.getOrientation();

Answer (score 1):

```
Display display;
int width;
int height;
```

in onCreate() add
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();

in onResume() add

```
if(width<height){
 //you can add your layout here (landscape)
}else{
    //you can add your layout here (portrait)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have two layouts, one for portrait and another for landscape orientation. You can use the same images if you use two layouts.

Comment: how can I check if the Orientation has been changed?

Comment: Display display;int width;int height;width = display.getWidth();
     height = display.getHeight();

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities,

**Option 1 :** You can have different XML layouts in `layout-port` ,`layout-land`,`drawable`,`drawable-land`. In those XML layouts, you can fix different sized images that matches your screen density.For different set of images, you can review on `ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi`,`xhdpi`.

**Option 2 :** You can go with Nine patch images.

If you find a better solution,Share it.

Cheers.

Comment: how can I check if the Orientation has been changed?

Comment: This will help you.http://www.anddev.org/detect_if_orientation_changes_from_portrait_to_landscape-t8689.html

Comment: Here is a snippet that makes your clear with your query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone/5072754#5072754

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet to recognize the configuration has been changed

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

 // Checks the orientation of the screen and do your action here

}
```

Cheers.