# Android how to test orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, junit4

I have an issue regarding unit testing android orientation shifts.
I have both Portrait and Landscape supported in my application and I have to test if the views hierarchy is correctly drawn when the orientation changes.

I have created two test methods to check this, and I have something like this:

```
public void testOnCreate() throws Exception {
    //Check all the activity components
    assertNotNull(activity);
    assertNotNull(application);

    //Check if the rights components are available on the screen
    assertNotNull(LayoutInflater.from(activity));
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    testOrientationPortrait();
}
```

On this particular case the tests pass, and the view hierarchy is drawn correctly. But when I try to test the landscape using:

```
public void testOrientationChange() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(activity);
    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //Check if the rights components are available on the screen
    assertNotNull(LayoutInflater.from(activity));
    testOrientationLandscape();
}
```

The orientation changes, but the view hierarchy fails, because views have the attributes from portrait.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks,
Ark

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2795833/1265724) link will help you

Comment: Well that shows me how to check for orientation. But the orientation is the only one that changes, for me. I need to be able to reinflate the new xml containing the view hierarchy for landscape.

Answer (score 2):

Override this method and do your changes in the method:

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


 }
```

Do not forget to add

```
 <activity

        android:configChanges="orientation"
        >
    </activity>
```

in your menifest.

And this can be used just to check the orientation .
    getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

Comment: `configChanges` is used when you have the same layout for both of the orientation, because views don't need to be redrawn, but I have separate layouts for land and protrait, so I don't used `configChanges` at all. So this doesn't help me at all.

Comment: This gives the orientation if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

    Log.e("On Config Change","LANDSCAPE");
}else{

    Log.e("On Config Change","PORTRAIT");
}

Comment: Yes I know. But as I said before, the orientation is changed, but the views have wrong attributes, because they are not redrawn for the new orientation. For instance I run the tests for the portrait, everything is ok, I run the tests for landscape, the orientation changes, but the views attributes remain the same.