# how to define different controls for portrait and landscape modes in android

Tags: android, android-layout

My app has three views in portrait  mode, a TextSwitcher, a custom view and a custom keyboard.
In the landscape mode I need to remove the TextSwitcher and add a ListView  in the right side.
I am new to android , I can define two layouts namely xxx and xxx-land, my problem is how to implement two branch of code, one for controling landscape and one for portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define all Views that appears in both resource file in you code 
and in the `onCreate()` in the `Activity` you can check the orientation to bind the Views to your class object .

example.

here we have 2 layout files that contain an ImageView in  both files and in the portrait file there is an `TextView` and in the landscape it contain a `Button` instead of the `TextView`

**my_layout.xml** in *layout-land*

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**my_layout.xml** in *layout-port* folder

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the Activity code

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // landscape views
    Button button1;

    // protrati views
    TextView textView1;

    // common views (shared between landscape and protrait mode)

    ImageView imageView1;

    public MyActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        imageView1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);//exist inside landscape file and portrait


        if(getScreenOrientation() == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }else{
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        }


        //when you want to access any thing that is not shared 
        //check the orientation 




    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        //let say that we want here to set a text on the textview  and it's available only for protrait 
        if(getScreenOrientation() == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            //won't be null :) so we can set the text
            textView1.setText("Hello Guys!");
        }

    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236110/671676
    public int getScreenOrientation() {
        Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
        if (getOrient.getWidth() == getOrient.getHeight()) {
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
        } else {
            if (getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight()) {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            }
        }
        return orientation;
    }
}
```

ask anything that you don't understand .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can proceed now.

Answer (score 3):

Set a flag based on current Orientation

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

and before accessing textswitcher or listview check the flag... and based on the flag take action for example in portrait mode make changes to Textswitcher, but in landscape dont as it will be null...