# Two columns for ListView or TableLayout in Landscape mode

Tags: android, listview, android-tablelayout

How can I get one column in portrait mode and two columns in landscape mode with a `ListView` or `TableLayout`.

For example, in Portrait:

- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3
- Element 4

And in Landscape :

- Element1 Element2
- Element3 Element4

I thought to use `ListView` with one column in portrait mode and `TableLayout` with two columns in landscape mode, but before that, I want to know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be way easy for you to use a GridView. You can set/choose number of columns on runtime and hence set them differently in portait vs landscape mode. That way, you'd just be manipulating a single view.

Comment: i think i will opt for this solution.

Comment: i'll test it and give you my feedback

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) rather than a TableLayout, since ListViews only create enough Views to fill the screen while a TableLayout will create every resource whether they are visible or not. In this way a TableLayout is slower and might even crash your app.

---

You can check the device's orientation with one of the answers from: [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2795833/1267661). Then if the orientation is:

- landscape, load your double View layout.
- portrait, load your basic, single View layout.

Loading different layouts in a ListView requires a simple custom Adapter. If you haven't written one before, here is a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) to help you.

Comment: A GridView is a subclass of ListView, so they are quite similar. But to create a fast, personalized layout you'll have to write a customized Adapter anyway. So if one if-statement is "way difficult" then definitely use a GridView. :) But you'll still need use two layouts or use an if-statement to determine the orientation.