# How to convert "onOrientationChanged" value to landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-orientation

How to convert **onOrientationChanged** methods `orientation` value to landscape and portrait to know the device orientation.

I have the following function that gets called every time when device orientations changes.
`public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)`

the parameter `orientation` is in between range 0 to 359.
So how can I get to know from these values if the device is in landscape mode or portrait mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check orientation on Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

Answer (score 1):

you can get orientation by using this

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{
  // do your stuff          
}
else
{
   // do your stuff         
}
```

Comment: I can't use onConfig change method as my application is using set orientation. So i am using onOrientationChanged method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the orientation in runtime with this code:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
//orientation will contain Surface.ROTATION_0 (no rotation), Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180 or Surface.ROTATION_270
int orientation = display.getRotation();
```

So, if you want to make something when changing the orientation you can override the `onConfigurationChanged` method.

And if you want to change the orientation in runtime you can use this (in example, change to portrait):

`setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

If want more details, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: `getRotation` every time returns me 0.

Comment: Put this on onConfigurationChanged and you will see it changing..but most of times it's 0 or 3..0 for portrait and 3  for landscape