# How to read orientation of Android Phone

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to read orientation of the phone. However when I use

`mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);`

It shows a warning The field Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION is deprecated.

I also have a warning when reading the gyroscope value.

Could someone help me to read these two data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current configuration, as used to determine which resources to retrieve etc, as available from the Resources' Configuration object as:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

or

```
    mWindowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    Log.d("ORIENTATION_TEST", "getOrientation(): " + mDisplay.getOrientation());
```

Comment: where can I call this method? Is it in                        onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)

Comment: No it is configuration. check out the link

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this post:
[Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

In short, use

```
 getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Of course, do not setup orientation by yourself in the manifest.xml.