# Android - get the sensor landscape orientation

Tags: java, android, orientation, sensors

I'm working at a game, and the orientation is sensorLandscape.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.fainosag.marioskate.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now my game can flip when I rotate my phone.
THe problem i have is that when the phone is flipped, the accelerometer value is also flipped..

How can I find out which android landscape orientation is ?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone

Comment: That question is about how to get the screen orientation (portrait / landscape / square), I want to know which landscape orientation is..i think that i want to see if the rotation is 0 or 180 degrees (landscape and landscape flipped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment because of low rep. (previous was just converted to comment)

So now I know what you want, I didn't understand you before. Try this:

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);    

Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

Check the degree with `Surface.ROTATION_0` (no rotation), `Surface.ROTATION_90`, `Surface.ROTATION_180`, or `Surface.ROTATION_270`.

See also here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29) and here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html