# Android: Get current device orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation, device-orientation

I have the activity orientation in manifest set as portrait. As i dont want my screen to rotate.

But On Clicking a button, I want to get the current device orientation (portrait or landscape) in Android ? I do not need continuous update from the sensors; just the current device orientation when i click the button is enough.

PS: Device Orientation is the way i am holding my Device. Do not mix this with screen orientation.

This is what i have done so far?

```
 int PORT=1,LAND=2;

 WindowManager windowService = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

 int rotation = windowService.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();        

    if (Surface.ROTATION_0 == rotation) {
        rotation = PORT;
    } else if(Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        rotation = PORT;
    } else if(Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation) {
        rotation = LAND;
    } else if(Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        rotation = LAND;
    }
 return rotation;
```

Even using the following method doesnt help

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

It always return 1 since my activity default is set a portrait.

Sample/example code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone

took me 10 secs. to google

Comment: Bart : Well, i went through the same. but its failing when the screen orientation is fixed.I want the device orientation on button click

Comment: You can run the code in the ActionListener for your button

Comment: try this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html

Comment: @Kushal, i am seeing the same behaviour, trying to come up with a solution as I'd like to know why this happens also. So apologies for my first comment, it doesn't seem to solve your problem indeed

Comment: @Kushal are you testing on device or emulator?

Comment: @Bart : No problem. I am currently testing on a device.

Comment: I think chances on others to help are low, since this has been marked duplicate, you might want to try and rephrase the question, indicating the things you've tried

Comment: Yep. Will have to do that

Answer (score 7):

Use this :)

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: This is failing when the screen orientation is fixed.

Comment: if it fails, please update your question, with code and stacktrace

Comment: By failing, i mean, it always returns the portrait mode value regardless of how i am holding my device.

Comment: @Kushal probably because you are getting the default orientation windowService.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
did you try our suggestion?

Comment: Yes I did.    

int rot = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
return rot;

Comment: returns 1 always, regardless how i am holding my device

Comment: How does this distinguish between landscape left / landscape right? Or portrait / portrait upside down?