# Get device orientation independent from current activity in Android

Tags: android, orientation

I have an activity that it's orientation is portrate (android:screenOrientation="portrait").

I need to get device orientation not orientation of my activity.

Is there any solution?

Comment: To me it seems like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236110/4550405) answer could solve your problem.