# Android. Fragment stays in activity after screen rotation issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a two variants of ***activity_main.xml*** (for portrait/landscape orientation). In this activity, user can choose items and browse detailed information about selected item.

In portraint orientation, fragments added to ***flFragmentContainer*** dynamically, after item choosing, details fragment replaces list fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In landscape orientation, fragments described in XML file statically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frgTaskList"
            android:name="com.exprod.xchecklist.fragments.TaskListFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_task_list" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frgTaskDetails"
            android:name="com.exprod.xchecklist.fragments.TaskDetailsFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_task_details">
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code of onCreate() method (of MainActivity).

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        TaskDetailsFragment taskDetailsFragment = (TaskDetailsFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frgTaskDetails);
        isDynamicMode = taskDetailsFragment == null || !taskDetailsFragment.isInLayout();
        if(isDynamicMode){
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment taskListFragment = new TaskListFragment();
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                transaction.add(R.id.flFragmentContainer, taskListFragment, TaskListFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
            }else{
                transaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, taskListFragment, TaskListFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
            }
            transaction.commit();            
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM:** When I rotate device to landscape orientation, I get twice calls of creation methods in first fragment (TaskListFragment) (*onCreateView(), onActivityCreated(), ...* ). This indicates that the old fragment remains in activity and recreated on orientation change.
How I can finally destroy old fragment??  I did not find the answer on the Internet.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two approaches to do what you want.

**Handle orientation change yourself:**

As described in [this document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange), you can prevent automatic `Activity` destroy and re-creation and handle orientation change yourself. In this case, you would remove the old `Fragment` before inflating a new layout into `Activity`.

**Remove the old Fragment after Activity re-creation:**

You could also add some logic that determines the orientation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone) (or use your current heuristic that sets `isDynamicMode`), and manually remove the unnecessary `Fragments` during `onCreate()`.

**The better way:**

Although it is possible to do what you want, I can't undertand why would you like to do it this way - you use `TaskListFragment` in both portrait and landscape configurations, therefore the most logical thing to do is to reuse it. Except for simplifying things, it will also let you keep the state of that `Fragment` on orientation change (which, I believe, is desirable in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Vasiliy answer. I follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange)
and add

***android:configChanges="oritentation"***

to my manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and the annoying behavior (fragment not attached to activity) when screen is rotated disappears

Answer (score -2):

Just add to your activity

 `@Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {}`

because implementation of this method in Android's Activity that is a parent of all Activities, saved Fragment.