# How to check if Orientation of device in Landscape Mode is clockwise or anticlockwise?

Tags: android, orientation

In my app I am using the front `camera` to create `preview frame`, before opening the `camera` I want to know if `Orientation` of device in `Landscape Mode` is `clockwise` (Right side) or `anticlockwise` (Left Side).

I am getting the `Orientation` by

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

**But let me know how to check it is clockwise or anticlockwise?**

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10453034/9868485

Comment: ya it works thanks

Comment: you welcome @NullPointer

Comment: @code4rox that answer uses deprecated api at api 16

Comment: @NullPointer If you don't mind, can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this snippet : *Activity.class*

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    if(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0){
        // clockwise
    }else if(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180){
        // anti-clockwise
    }
} else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    //portrait
}
```

---

Not just to check at the start, but you should also check that if it's getting changed in runtime too.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //landscape
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //portrait
    }
}
```